# Javers with simple diff returning ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_ID with an abstract entity

Tags: java, javers

**Exception is happening when trying to find simple diff but its not throwing exception if I change it to MappingStyle.BEAN **

```
**.withMappingStyle(MappingStyle.BEAN)**
```

> JaversException ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_ID: Found Entity instance
> 'Employee' with null Id-property 'id'     at
> org.javers.core.metamodel.type.EntityType.getIdOf(EntityType.java:115)
> at
> org.javers.core.metamodel.type.EntityType.createIdFromInstance(EntityType.java:122)

```
@SuperBuilder
    @MappedSuperclass
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(of=  "id")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public abstract class BaseEntity   {
        
        @DiffIgnore
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid",updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)    
        @GeneratedValue
        private UUID id;
        
        @DiffIgnore
        @Column(name="\"createDateTime\"", updatable=false, nullable=false)
        @CreationTimestamp
        private LocalDateTime createDateTime;
    
        @DiffIgnore
        @LastModifiedBy
        @Column(name="\"createUser\"", updatable=false, nullable=false, length=100)
        private String createUser;
    
        @DiffIgnore
        @Column(name="\"modifiedDateTime\"", nullable=false)
        @UpdateTimestamp
        private LocalDateTime modifiedDateTime;
    
        @DiffIgnore
        @LastModifiedBy
        @Column(name="\"modifiedUser\"", nullable=false, length=100)
        private String modifiedUser;    
    }

    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    @SuperBuilder
    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @TypeName("Employee")
    public class Employee extends BaseEntity {
    
        public Employee(String name) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        private String name;
    
        private String position;
    
        private int salary;
    
        private int age;
    
        private Employee boss;
    
        @Builder.Default
        private List<Employee> subordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    
        private Address primaryAddress;
    
        private Set<String> skills;
    }


        @Test
    void compareTwoEntitiesTest() {
      //given
      Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
              .withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE)
              .build();
    
      UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
      Employee oldEntity = Employee.builder()
              .id(id)
              .name("Frodo")
              .age(40)
              .position("Townsman")
              .salary(10_000)
              .boss(new Employee("Gandalf"))
              .primaryAddress(new Address("Shire"))
              .skills(Set.of("management"))
              .subordinates(List.of(new Employee("Sam")))
              .createDateTime(LocalDateTime.now())
              .createUser("ch")
              .build();
    
      Employee newEntity = Employee.builder()
              .id(id)
              .name("Frodo")
              .age(41)
              .position("Hero")
              .salary(12_000)
              .boss(new Employee("Gandalf"))
              .primaryAddress(new Address("Mordor"))
              .skills(Set.of("management", "agile coaching"))
              .subordinates(List.of(new Employee("Sam"), new Employee("Sméagol")))
              .createDateTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1))
              .createUser("zy")
              .build();
    
      //when
      Diff diff = javers.compare(oldEntity, newEntity);
      System.out.println(diff.prettyPrint());
     
 

    //then
      assertThat(diff.getChanges()).hasSize(7);
```